# Finding Specific Points on a Curve

Tags: graphing-functions

I currently have a curve and would like to plot some points down on the curve given that i have the mid point, start point and end point. I'm hoping 2 evenly spread out points between the start and mid point and also 2 evenly spread out points between the mid point and end point.

I've attached an image of what i'm looking to achieve.

[Curve with points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5Mao.png)

Not too sure how to achieve this and any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You can try using an interpolating polynomial with 7 points on [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/shspxanjst).